# CSV File Sender Information with App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to extract the details of Emails(Email Address,Subject,Date)from Gmail Inbox that contain CSV file in attachment. But I have managed to extract CSV file from certain email address. Is there any way that we can get the information of all emails that have CSV file in attachment? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 function import() {
   var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:"example@gmail.com"');

  if (threads.length===0)
    return;
 var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
 var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
 var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  attachment.setContentType('text/csv');

 // Is the attachment a CSV file
 if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");

    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");


  // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
   sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
   sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

// GmailApp.moveMessageToTrash(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `var messages = threads[0].getMessages();` indicates that you are running your code only for the first thread.
- If you want to retrieve attachements from all threads, you need to iterate over your threads with a loop.
- In order to receive the sender of a message you can use the [getFrom()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom) method.

*The following sample retrieves the senders of all the last messages of your threads that have a CSV attachment. The senders are stored in an array:*

```
 function import() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox from:"example@gmail.com"');
  if (threads.length==0)
    return;
  var senders = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
   var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
   var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
   var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
    attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
   // Is the attachment a CSV file
   if (attachment.getContentType() == "text/csv") {
      var sender = message.getFrom();
      senders.push(sender);
     // do whatever else you want to do
     ...
    }
  }
  Logger.log(senders);
}
```

> This sample will iterate through the last message of each thread. If
>   you want to iterate through all messages of all threads, you need to
>   implement a second, nested loop.

Comment: It is correct @ziganotschka if I want to retrieve attachments from all threads. But As I mentioned, I just want to retrieve the address of those particular emails that have CSV files in attachment.

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood your question. I will modify my answer.